# Swift Sprites animation: xCode doesn't read my atlas folder

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I am making a simple animation with a bear moving back and forth. My issue is that my code doesn't recognise my atlas folder (BearImages.atlas) or doesn't recognise the images into it. I don't know what I am doing wrong and I can't figure out. Can you explain to me as I am 5 years old, why xCode doesn't recognise my folder or my images into it?

ScreenShot:

[Click to open Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDMJt.png)

My code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var bear : SKSpriteNode!
    var bearWalkingFrames : [SKTexture]!

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        backgroundColor = (UIColor.blackColor())

        let bearAnimatedAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "BearImages")
        var walkFrames = [SKTexture]()
        print(bearAnimatedAtlas)

        let numImages = bearAnimatedAtlas.textureNames.count
        for var i=1; i<=numImages/2; i++ {
            let bearTextureName = "bear\(i)"
            walkFrames.append(bearAnimatedAtlas.textureNamed(bearTextureName))
        }

        bearWalkingFrames = walkFrames

        let firstFrame = bearWalkingFrames[0]
        bear = SKSpriteNode(texture: firstFrame)
        bear.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        addChild(bear)

        walkingBear()
    }

    func walkingBear() {
        //This is our general runAction method to make our bear walk.
        bear.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
            SKAction.animateWithTextures(bearWalkingFrames,
                timePerFrame: 0.1,
                resize: false,
                restore: true)),
                       withKey:"walkingInPlaceBear")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: how did you create this atlas?

Answer (score 0):

This may not solve your issue, but it is probably the most likely cause...

1. Click on your project "`pierro peguin learning`" within the project navigator window on the left
2. Click on the `Build Phases` tab
3. Under the `Copy Bundle Resources` section, make sure `BearImages.atlas` is there
4. If it is not, add it with the plus button

Comment: Is your code crashing? And what file format are the images within your atlas folder?

Comment: png. No my code doesn't crash but it displays an X image with white background

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems find so I presume it must be the image names or you didn't copy the atlas folder into your project (you just referenced it)

1st thing you should do is to use xCode 7 new atlas feature to store your atlas in the asset catalogue instead of just copying an atlas folder into the project. Try that first and see if it makes a difference.

Apple also recommends this approach for performance and better organisation.

If that doesnt work....

1) What formats are your images in? They normally should be in PNG format.

2) Can you show the content of the atlas folder?

3) Are you not seeing any animations at all or do you get the white square with the red X?

Generally, and not specific to your question, why are you creating 2 arrays for the images?
Just use the bearWalkingFrames array and append the images directly. Seems complicated to create a second array (walkFrames) append the images and than set bearWalkingFrames to that array.